# Restoring Windows Apps (UWP) after cloning an internal disk drive

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, cloning, uwp

I've just cloned an internal HDD 1TB to a different 2TB disk using Minitool Partition Wizard, also expanding the partition size to the full available space. This computer is running Windows 10 patched to version 2004 on a separate drive. I've also re-mapped the Drive Letter to the one used by the previous disk.

Unfortunately upon restarting I've noticed that Windows is unable to locate any UWP app installed on this drive - when I try booting them I get an error telling me that the app is "Offline" and Windows 10 can't find it.

Regular win32 applications (steam, EGS, Origin) have no issue whatsoever mapping their old files to the new drive. I can only assume that UWP apps locate their files using a different device namespace rather than regular drive letters.

Is there a way to fix this and map the old apps to the new drive? Are such paths store somewhere in the registry?

I mean, I think I could probably just re-download them to fix this but it's around 300GB in games and apps that we're talking about.

Comment: Cloning a drive should have been straight-forward if you had physically replaced the disk. As it is, I suggest to [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: @harrymc Windows 10 by itself is fine, the cloned drive was a completely different partition than the system disk. It's just the UWP apps on it that are "missing".

Comment: Repair install will restore the registry. I hope you haven't left the old disk in its place.

Comment: Wouldn't a system restore just keep the current paths? As far as Windows is concerned the apps are just "offline" and stored on the old drive, it has no reason to look after them on a completely different disk.

Comment: If the old disk is disconnected, and the new one is connected in its place, this should set Windows to a consistent state.

Comment: I have this same issue, but didn't clone anything: I used the drive as an external drive using an enclosure, now this same drive is internally installed in the system. But Windows Store thinks it's a different thing, so I can't access them and can't even free up the space they occupy.

Answer (score 0):

I highlighted The C Drive with my arrow keys, and did **Computer > Rename** using the top nav bar.

Editing the C Drive name, and a RESTART fixes all the broken Windows apps.

Answer (score -1):

I just spent several hours on this one. eg: it boots ok and apps all work, except for windows stuff like Disc Management, Device manager, Command Prompt, Windows Explorer (if you right click on the 'C' drive), Microsoft Edge, Task Manager, etc. which all hang up forcing a reboot.
The answer was to change the name of the C drive and reboot. Because a right-click on C drive in Explorer hangs up, I had to use ThisPC, Drive C, and the Rename toolbar button.
I think these functions were looking for the original HDD.